# dataframe math in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**TOTALLY RE WROTE ORIGINAL QUESTION**

I read raw data from a csv file "CloseWeight4.csv"

```
df=pd.read_csv('CloseWeights4.csv')
Date      Symbol    ClosingPrice    Weight
3/1/2010    OGDC    116.51         0.1820219
3/2/2010    OGDC    117.32         0.1820219
3/3/2010    OGDC    116.4          0.1820219
3/4/2010    OGDC    116.58         0.1820219
3/5/2010    OGDC    117.61         0.1820219
3/1/2010    WTI      78.7          0.5348142
3/2/2010    WTI      79.68         0.5348142
3/3/2010    WTI      80.87         0.5348142
3/4/2010    WTI      80.21         0.5348142
3/5/2010    WTI      81.5          0.5348142
3/1/2010    FX       85.07         0.1312427
3/2/2010    FX       85.1077       0.1312427
3/3/2010    FX       85.049        0.1312427
3/4/2010    FX       84.9339       0.1312427
3/5/2010    FX       84.8          0.1312427
3/1/2010    PIB      98.1596499    0.1519211
3/2/2010    PIB      98.1596499    0.1519211
3/3/2010    PIB      98.1764222    0.1519211
3/4/2010    PIB      98.1770656    0.1519211
3/5/2010    PIB      98.1609364    0.1519211
```

From Which I generate a dataframe df2

```
df2=df.iloc[:,0:3].pivot('Date', 'Symbol', 'ClosingPrice')

df2
Out[10]: 
Symbol           FX    OGDC        PIB    WTI
Date                                         
2010-03-01  85.0700  116.51  98.159650  78.70
2010-03-02  85.1077  117.32  98.159650  79.68
2010-03-03  85.0490  116.40  98.176422  80.87
2010-03-04  84.9339  116.58  98.177066  80.21
2010-03-05  84.8000  117.61  98.160936  81.50
```

from this I calculate returns using:

```
ret=np.log(df2/df2.shift(1))

In [12] ret

Out[12]: 
Symbol            FX      OGDC       PIB       WTI
Date                                              
2010-03-01       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
2010-03-02  0.000443  0.006928  0.000000  0.012375
2010-03-03 -0.000690 -0.007873  0.000171  0.014824
2010-03-04 -0.001354  0.001545  0.000007 -0.008195
2010-03-05 -0.001578  0.008796 -0.000164  0.015955
```

I have weights of each security from df

```
df3=df.iloc[:,[1,3]].drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)

df3
Out[14]: 
          Weight
Symbol          
OGDC    0.182022
WTI     0.534814
FX      0.131243
PIB     0.151921
```

I am trying to get the following weighted return results for each day but don't know how to do the math in  pandas:

```
Date        Portfolio_weighted_returns
2010-03-02        0.008174751
2010-03-03        0.006061657
2010-03-04       -0.005002414
2010-03-05        0.009058151
where the Portfolio_weighted_returns of 2010-03-02 is calculated as follows:
0.006928*0.182022+.012375*0.534814+0.000443*0.131243+0*0.151921 = 0.007937512315
```

I then need to have these results multiplied by a decay factor where the decay factor is defineD as decFac =decay^(t).  Using a decay = 0.5 gives decFac values of:

```
Date        decFac
2010-03-02  0.0625
2010-03-03  0.125
2010-03-04  0.25
2010-03-05  0.5
```

I then need to take the SQRT of the sum of the squared Portfolio_weighted_returns for each day multiplied by the respective decFac as such:

```
SQRT(Sum(0.008174751^2*.0625+0.006061657^2*.125+(-0.005002414^2)*.25+.009058151^2*.5)) = 0.007487
```

Comment: I added a comment in the question stating that I am not sure how to do the math in pandas.  the array of decay values is a function of how many days in the past the portfolio weighted return is and I am not sure how to do that and I am not sure how to get a weighted portfolio return number for each day as well

Comment: Are the portfolio returns basically the sum of the returns of each security on a given day right?

Comment: @John, could you also post a formula for your `math`?

Comment: weighted by the provided weights of each security, yes

Comment: I think the result might not be as posted... I'm posting some code now, let me know what you think

Comment: Hi Evan54, my returns are log returns ret=np.log(data/data.shift(1))  maybe that is why they are different than you expected. . . .

Comment: I apologize MaxU, in finance it is standard practice to use log returns, I agree I should have pointed that out

Comment: Pretty sure the math is wrong... `0.000443 * 0.182022 + 0.006928 * 0.534814 + 0 * 0.131243 + 0.012375 * 0.151921=0.00566585` which should be the first value of `Portfolio_weighted_returns`

Comment: your multiplying the numbers by the wrong weights, s/b 0.000443*.131243+.006928*.182022+.012819*.534814+0*.151921

Comment: @John can you [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39317959/edit) your question to include necessary information? I don't think financial background is cruical here. Just give the formula.

Comment: I as rewriting the entire thing

Comment: I rewrote the question,

Comment: @John, can you explain where does `.012819` come from in the `0.006928*0.182022+.012819*0.534814+0.000443*0.131243+0*0.151921` formula

Comment: sorry, corrected number

Comment: @John, i've added an answer - please check the numbers

Comment: @John I think the portfolio values are wrong, looking at the first value the `0.008174751` and the "manual" calculation gives `0.007937512315` as per your updated question. Also, with regards to the decaying weights I'm not sure if this is relevant but you may be interrested in `.rolling_apply` functions, where you basically apply this kind of "averaging/fiiltering" over the 5 previous days for a timeseries of data

Answer (score 1):

IIUC you can do it this way:

```
In [267]: port_ret = ret.dot(df3)

In [268]: port_ret
Out[268]:
              Weight
Date
2010-03-01       NaN
2010-03-02  0.007938
2010-03-03  0.006431
2010-03-04 -0.004278
2010-03-05  0.009902

In [269]: decay = 0.5

In [270]: decay_df = pd.DataFrame({'decFac':decay**np.arange(len(ret), 0, -1)}, index=ret.index)

In [271]: decay_df
Out[271]:
             decFac
Date
2010-03-01  0.03125
2010-03-02  0.06250
2010-03-03  0.12500
2010-03-04  0.25000
2010-03-05  0.50000

In [272]: (port_ret.Weight**2 * decay_df.decFac).sum() ** 0.5
Out[272]: 0.007918790111274962
```

`port_ret.Weight**2 * decay_df.decFac`

```
In [277]: port_ret.Weight**2 * decay_df.decFac
Out[277]:
Date
2010-03-01         NaN
2010-03-02    0.000004
2010-03-03    0.000005
2010-03-04    0.000005
2010-03-05    0.000049
dtype: float64
```

Comment: when i run port_ret = ret.dot(df3)  I get this error message: ValueError: matrices are not aligned

Comment: @John, make sure that # of columns in `ret` == `len(df3)`

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
```

### define the variables

```
data = np.mat('''  85.0700  116.51  98.159650  78.70;
85.1077  117.32  98.159650  79.68;
85.0490  116.40  98.176422  80.87;
84.9339  116.58  98.177066  80.21;
84.8000  117.61  98.160936  81.50''')

cols = ['FX', 'OGDC' , 'PIB' , 'WTI']
dts = pd.Series( data=pd.date_range('2010-03-01', '2010-03-05'), name='Date' )
df2 = pd.DataFrame( data=data, columns=cols, index=dts )
# this is your df3 variable
wgt = pd.DataFrame( data=[0.131243, 0.182022, 0.151921, 0.534814], index=pd.Series(cols, name='Symbol') , columns=['Weight'] )
```

To calculate daily returns I use the `.shift` operator

```
# Calculate the daily returns for each security
df_ret = np.log( df2 / df2.shift(1) )
#                   FX      OGDC       PIB       WTI
# Date                                              
# 2010-03-01       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
# 2010-03-02  0.000443  0.006928  0.000000  0.012375
# 2010-03-03 -0.000690 -0.007873  0.000171  0.014824
# 2010-03-04 -0.001354  0.001545  0.000007 -0.008195
# 2010-03-05 -0.001578  0.008796 -0.000164  0.015955
```

You need to multiply the `Weight` column of `wgt` with `ret` to get the desired result. `wgt['Weight']` will return a `pd.Series` which is more like a 1-D array than a 2D array which a `pd.DataFrame` can be generally thought of.

```
df_wgt_ret = wgt['Weight'] * df_ret
#                   FX      OGDC           PIB       WTI
# Date                                                  
# 2010-03-01       NaN       NaN           NaN       NaN
# 2010-03-02  0.000081  0.003705  0.000000e+00  0.001880
# 2010-03-03 -0.000126 -0.004210  2.242285e-05  0.002252
# 2010-03-04 -0.000247  0.000826  8.609014e-07 -0.001245
# 2010-03-05 -0.000287  0.004704 -2.156434e-05  0.002424
```

Sum over the columns (axis=1) to get the portfolio returns. Note this returns a `pd.Series` not a dataframe

```
port_ret = df_wgt_ret.sum(axis=1)
# Date
# 2010-03-01         NaN
# 2010-03-02    0.005666
# 2010-03-03   -0.002061
# 2010-03-04   -0.000664
# 2010-03-05    0.006820
```

Finally, multiply the decay rate with the portfolio, note that because the operation happens over the columns you need to

```
total_ret = (port_ret * sr_dec).sum()
final_res = total_ret**0.5
```

### The One liner

I'm assuming `decFac` is a dataframe with column name `decFac` and using `df3` and `ret` as you've defined them.

```
result = (( (df3.Weight * ret).sum(axis=1)**2 * decFac.decFac ).sum())**.5
```

Comment: Evan54, looks like your solution would work, but the data I provided was sample data, not the entire datafile.  Can you rephrase your answer using the dataframes df2 and df3 rather than hard coded numbers (data and cols for example)